# Remove attribute from the database

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes, patches

When the patch is uninstalled then the attribute is also removed from the database in the Magento 2
is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "the patch is uninstalled"? How do you uninstall the patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created a patch most probably you have implemented `Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface` if you check in Magento Framework there is another Interface Related to Patch i.e`Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface`

if You Implement `PatchRevertableInterface` to you Data Patch you can implement `revert()` functionality as well

Like this

```
class YourDataPatch implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function apply()
    {
       // Add code on Applying Patch        
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function revert()
    {
         // Add code on Revering Patch i.e Delete Attribute
    }
}
```

Patch can be reverted When you Uninstall Module  [Remove Composer & Non-Composer Patches](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/patches/#reverting-data-patches)

Deleting Data can Create Data Inconsistency in DB so Please Do with Great Care