# Magento 2. Patch, How to revert the schema when we Uninstall the module?

Tags: magento2, patches

> I have created a patch in the "Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Schema" path
> We have to use two things :

- > 1st is to update the existing table schema from apply function
- > And 2nd schema once the module is uninstalled.

> We observer that on the installation(setup:upgrade) everything is going good

> But it not working correctly at the time of Uninstall(module:uninstall  Prince_PatchExample) the module

```
    ?php
namespace Prince\PatchExample\Setup\Patch\Schema;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class MyNewPatchFile implements SchemaPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    protected $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup)
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $connection = $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('my_custom_table');

        $connection->addColumn(
            $tableName,
            'my_status',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => false,
                'comment' => 'New Column'
            ]
        );
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $connection = $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('my_custom_table');
        $connection->dropColumn($tableName, 'my_status');
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: This will help you according to your requirements : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/362710/remove-attribute-from-the-database

Comment: Hello @RanaZain,  I have already used the related interface and its revert function you can see over the code snippet,  Please let me know if I missed the code.